# If-else to Switch in Java

Tags: java, switch-statement

I have this `if-else` statement that takes an 2d-array as argument and checks if it's `null` or empty and I'm trying to convert it to a `switch` statement because I want to insert a `break` line.

```
public static void method (int[][]matrix, int x){
    if (matrix == null){ // Matrix is an int[][]
                System.out.println("It's NULL");
                            // I want to insert a break line here
            } else if (matrix.length == 0){ // Checks if it is empty
                System.out.println("Empty array");
                           // I want to insert a break line here
            } else {
                    // Calculates other things if it's not NULL or empty
                }
}
```

I tried to do `switch(matrix)` but Eclipse shows a message saying that it cannot switch on a value of type `int[][]`.

Comment: Always post exact error messages. What's the exact message?

Comment: What do you mean by "I want to insert a `break` line here"? Does the `if` somehow not work properly? It can do anything you can do with a `switch` (and then some).

Comment: Why do you want to break there? The other conditions won't be checked if the first one is true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's right.

A `switch` in Java does not do "complex" objects (or fancy conditions and pattern matches), just primitives, enums, and Strings.

You have to stick with your `if` statements (which is not too bad anyway).

Comment: And do you have any idea on how can I stop my code after it checks something? I cannot use a `break` as it's not a `switch` statement neither `return` as I'm inside a `void` method

Comment: You *can* `return` from `void` methods as well. Just a `return;` on its own (no value). And the `else` kind of takes the role of `break` in a `switch`. With `else`, you won't fall-through into the next "case".

Comment: Now I understand! Thank you